# Global variable - jquery

Tags: jquery, callback, global-variables

everyone. I have following example script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(tweets) {
        for(i in tweets) {
            tweet = tweets[i];
            $("#tweet-list").append(tweet.text + "<hr />");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now I want to refresh the data gotten from the url when clicked. I added a global variable 'content' and tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").click(function(){ 
    var content="";
    var url =  "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(tweets) {
        for(i in tweets) {
            tweet = tweets[i];
            content+=tweet.text + "<hr />";
        }
    });
    $("#tweet-list").html(content); 
});
});
</script>
```

But it showed nothing, then I thought maybe that's because '$("#tweet-list").html(content);' executed before 'content+=tweet.text + "

---

"', so i tried to add a callback function after():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").click(function(){ 
    var content="";
    var url =  "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(tweets,after) {
        for(i in tweets) {
            tweet = tweets[i];
            content+=tweet.text + "<hr />";
        }
    after(content){$("#tweet-list").html(content);}; 
    });

});
});
</script>
```

still not working (showing nothing), any help? thx.

Comment: Define doesn't work. "Doesn't work" is never an error message or a good problem description.

Comment: Remove all of the HTML; it is unnecessary to understanding your problem.

Comment: @adeneo Surely you jest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous, so you'll have to wait for a response and some data to come back before you can do anything with it. When you're trying to use the content **after** the ajax function, it's not done yet, and there is no content. You'll have to do that inside the callback when there is actual content to append and the ajax call is completed :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").click(function(){ 
        var content="",
            url =  "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json";
        $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(tweets,after) {
            for(key in tweets) {
                if (tweets.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    content+=tweets[key].text + "<hr />";
                }
            }
            $("#tweet-list").html(content); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am new to jquery, just think too much..Thx for your help.

Comment: @trivial You might want to accept this answer if it solved your problem. You can do that by checking the tick mark at the right. Doing so indicates that your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the HTML once the AJAX request has completed:

```
$.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(tweets) {
    var content = "";
    for(i in tweets) {
        var tweet = tweets[i];
        content += tweet.text + "<hr />";  
    }
    $("#tweet-list").html(content);
});
```

Also, you don't need globals here, so use the `var` keyword.